# run-time error '1004': Unable to get the Combin property of the WorksheetFunction class

Tags: vba, excel

I have VBA function within a workbook in Excel 2013 that calculates a p-value based on a poisson distribution.  When the *events* variable in the code below exceeds 1029 I get **run-time error '1004': Unable to get the Combin property of the WorksheetFunction class**. So long as the sum of events1 and events2 remains at 1029 or below there are no issues and the macro executes properly.

Is anyone aware of a way to get this to function properly with higher numbers? Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

```
Sub poisson_meansB()
    Dim events1 As Long
    Dim events2 As Long
    Dim days1 As Long
    Dim days2 As Long

    events1 = Sheet1.Range("B6").Value
    events2 = Sheet1.Range("C6").Value
    days1 = Sheet1.Range("B7").Value
    days2 = Sheet1.Range("C7").Value

    If events2 > 0 Then
    events = events1 + events2
    p_c = days1 / (days1 + days2)
    p_lo = 0
    p_hi = 0
    For i = 0 To events1
        poisson_p_value_term = Application.WorksheetFunction.Combin(events, i) * Application.WorksheetFunction.Power(p_c, i) * Application.WorksheetFunction.Power(1 - p_c, events - i)
        p_lo = p_lo + poisson_p_value_term
    Next i
    For i = events1 To events
        poisson_p_value_term = Application.WorksheetFunction.Combin(events, i) * Application.WorksheetFunction.Power(p_c, i) * Application.WorksheetFunction.Power(1 - p_c, events - i)
        p_hi = p_hi + poisson_p_value_term
    Next i
    p = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(2 * p_lo, 2 * p_hi)
    Sheet1.Range("C13") = p
    Else
    Sheet1.Range("C13") = "-"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The largest allowed number in Excel is: `1.79769313486231E+308`. Do you know if the resulting number from your calculation would be greater than that?  If so, that is what is causing the error.

Comment: Thanks, but even if I set events1 to 1 and events2 to 1029, the result of the COMBIN function is 1030 and I still get the error.  Changing it to events1 = 1 and events2 = 1028 the result of the COMBIN function is 1029 and the error does not occur. So it doesn't appear that is the issue.

Comment: Nevermind, it's the second COMBIN function that is causing the issue and you're correct in that it is reaching that upper limit.  

From COMBIN(1030,500) to COMBIN(1030,530) the result exceeds 1.797E+308. 

COMBIN(1030,499) = 1.7E+308
COMBIN(1030,531) = 1.7E+308

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Excel 2013, the largest positive number that can be returned by a formula is 1.7976931348623158e+308  It is likely that your numbers work out to a value greater than that under the circumstances you describe.  You can confirm this by trying to execute the COMBIN function on the worksheet using the factors for the variables and seeing if it returns a #NUM error.

One possible solution is to install the [XNumbers add-in](http://www.thetropicalevents.com/Xnumbers60.htm) and use its xComb_big function. XNumbers is a free tool that allows the use of large numbers and increased precision. It is said to work on versions of Excel from 97-2010.  I don't know if it will work with 2013.  But if it does, it can be configured to work with exponents up to 2147000000 and up to 32760 significant digits (you may not want that much, but it is configurable, and the default installation has fewer digits).

Answer (score -1):

I'd wager this problem will disappear if you explicitly declare all your variables:
`events`, 
`p_c`, 
`p_lo`, 
`p_hi`, 
`i`,
`poisson_p_value_term`