# Binomial European Options Pricing Model

Tags: vba, excel

I created a program, using VBA, to calculate the European Call option price, as follows:

```
Private Sub CallPrice_Click()
Dim K As Single
Dim So As Single
Dim r As Single
Dim T As Single
Dim sigma As Single
Dim u As Single
Dim d As Single
Dim p As Single
Dim CP As Single
Dim M As Single
Dim S As Single
Dim CB As Double
Dim n As Integer
Dim i As Integer

K = Cells(2, 2)
So = Cells(3, 2)
r = Cells(4, 2)
T = Cells(5, 2)
sigma = Cells(6, 2)
n = Cells(7, 2)
u = Exp(sigma * Sqr(T / n))
d = 1 / u
p = (Exp(r * T / n) - d) / (u - d)
CP = 0
For i = 0 To n Step 1
    M = WorksheetFunction.Max(So * (u ^ i) * d ^ (n - i) - K, 0)
    CB = WorksheetFunction.Combin(n, i)
    S = M * CB * (p ^ n) * (1 - p) ^ (n - i)
    CP = CP + S
Next i
Cells(9, 2) = CP / (1 + r) ^ n
End Sub
```

Here is the layout of the spreadsheet:

[image]

When I ran the program, the error occurred.

[image]

[image]

Could someone here explain what is wrong in my program and how to fix it?

Comment: What are the values of `n` and `i` when the error occurs?

Comment: @Rory I dunno how to check those values :'(

Comment: View --> Immediate window; then in immediate window type ? <variable>  e.g. ? i and then click enter. Can I guess that the number in i is 162?

Comment: @Rory I got `n = 5000` and `i = 162`

Comment: combin(5000,162) produces a number that is to big for a double to hold.

Comment: @99moorem So what should I assign the variable `CB` then to handle the number C(5000,162)?

Comment: It may be that the function Combin doesnt like that large of a value I am not sure - only say that as even in a worksheet it does not like it get #NUM!. Hopefully @Rory has an idea!

Comment: You can't, I don't think. It wouldn't work in a cell either.

Comment: A quick search revealed an answer on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875432/run-time-error-1004-unable-to-get-the-combin-property-of-the-worksheetfunctio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your equation for S correct? It seems like it should be:

```
S = M * CB * (p ^ i) ...
```

instead of

```
S = M * CB * (p ^ n) ...
```

If your equation is indeed wrong, then you can use BINOMDIST instead of COMBIN, because by definition:

```
Binom_Dist(i, n, p, False) = (p ^ i) * (1 - p) ^ (n - i) * Combin(n, i)
```

So your code would be:

```
S = M * WorksheetFunction.Binom_Dist(i, n, p, False)
```

instead of

```
CB = WorksheetFunction.Combin(n, i)
S = M * CB * (p ^ n) * (1 - p) ^ (n - i)
```

BINOMDIST is not as sensitive to large n, i.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an overflow error. If you check on a work sheet:

```
COMBIN(5000, 161) = 3.3E+307
COMBIN(5000, 162) = #NUM!

COMBIN(5000, 4838) = #NUM!
COMBIN(5000, 4839) = 3.3E+307
```

Remember that the number of combinations increases exponentially up until the halfway point in which it will start to go down at an inverse rate.